# Return an sort array whitout an foreach

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have this array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [type] => 1
        [s] => 123
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [os_type] => 2
        [token] => fdsfsdfsd
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => 1
        [s] => oidshiufjsd
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [type] => 1
        [s] => sdjfdhskjfdsh
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [type] => 1
        [s] => sdjfhdsfkjds
    )
```

I wabt to sort this array by the key `type` whitout foreach. I want to get something like that :

```
1 => Array(
      [id] => 1
      [s]  => 123
     ),
     .....
2 => Array(
      [id] => 2,
      [s]  => fdsfsdfsd
      )
  ......
```

The idea is to build this array by type. Please help me.. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: what happen when type matched?

Comment: It looks like you are not sorting the array, but rearranging it. You are unsetting the key `type` and using it's value as the new array keys. You are in fact building a new array and I'm pretty sure that can't (and shouldn't) be done w/out looping through the array.

Comment: also you have to types:- `type` and `os_type`? Is it a typo?

Comment: More effective solution:-https://eval.in/706407 (now you can sort by key and all data will preserve too)